# Mongodb Natural Language query

Tags: nlp

I am using node.JS and mongodb for my app.
I want to add natural language search there, so I need to convert string to mongodb query.
For example if user search `documents from John created yesterday`

The output should be like

```
{
    creqte_at: { $gte: yesterday },
    ownerName: { "John" }
}
```

Is there some modules ?

Answer (score 0):

there's a few people who've written papers, but I don't know any NPM modules. 
example

https://www.slideshare.net/PyData/querying-your-database-in-natural-language-by-daniel-moisset-pydata-sv-2014?next_slideshow=1

others seem to be using neo4j to model sentence structures and relations as graphs, and python to do the NLP processing. 
http://www.lyonwj.com/2015/06/16/nlp-with-neo4j/

You can look at NaturalNode as a JS version of some of Python's NLTK features.
https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural